# Getting back into Windows programming

Tags: c++

I've been out of the Microsoft stack for a while now, been focused on Linux, open source stuff and web development in PHP. I used to do some desktop app development and some DirectX stuff on Windows in Dev Studio (all C and C++).

I'd like to brush up on the MS stuff just to keep up on what's going on. I've installed MSVC++ 2008 Express but I'm looking for a little side-project to play with. Given my background in C/C++ and familiarity with MFC and STL, what would be a good way to jump back in?

Comment: This question is too open ended

Comment: I agree. It depends on your interests. This just a slightly more directed version of "I want to program something, what should it be?"

Comment: It's more that I want to program what people on MS platform are programming. i.e. given someone with my background, if I'd stayed on Windows programming then what would I be doing now? Is this something I should clarify in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been developing on Microsoft stack since 1997, starting with C/C++/MFC/ATL, but all of the recent projects were on .NET platform (C#), so I would recommend learning .NET/C#. C/C++ still has its place, but it loses relevance rather rapidly. If not for legacy projects, we would not even bother with C/C++. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: depend he mentioned DirectX and I don't give a go to c# to do directx stuff ... After for normal WinForm app c# is far better.

Comment: I love C# for DirectX stuff - SlimDX is fantastic, quite fast, and much nicer to develop in than C++ for Direct3D.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get back into modern Windows programming you should learn C#/WPF.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to get back into windows programming C# ASP.NET 3.5 is a fairly common and current language and framework to start with.  This is the direction that the masses of C# .NET guys have been migrating as of late and you may be able to find a wealth of communities and bloggers contributing to that scene.

From the sounds of it, however, it looks like you were doing something along the lines of game development (DirectX and C++).  Although more niche and slightly dated there are still a great deal of coders using the language.  One of my favorite stops is [GameDev.net](http://www.gamedev.net) because of the active community and active forums.

Good luck and have fun!

Comment: I used to hang out at gamedev.net years ago. The DirectX stuff was for fun on the side but is more representative of what I find fun I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You could check out the VC++2010 beta, which comes with C++0x support and some [MFC updates](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Charles/Pat-Brenner-Visual-Studio-2010-MFC-and-Windows-7/). 
Since you're experienced with Linux, you might want to check out [Qt for Windows](http://qt.nokia.com/products/platform/qt-for-windows) too.

Comment: Didn't know MFC was still being developed. Have to have a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

I fancy [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org) very much. It portable, effective and easy to learn especially if you've got some experience from MFC.